# select rows where ID has variation of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns, an ID, and the other a value which is either 0 or 1.  I am trying to select all Rows for the ID where it has a 0 and a 1, for example,

```
RowNumber ------------- ID   ------- value  
1   ------------------- 001  -------   1  
2   ------------------- 001  -------     1  
3   ------------------- 001  -------     1  
4   ------------------- 002  -------     1  
5   ------------------- 002  -------     0  
6   ------------------- 003  -------     1  
7   ------------------- 003  -------     1  
8   --------------------004 -------      1  
9  -------------------- 004   -------    0   
10  ------------------- 004   -------    1
```

The result should select rows 4, 5, 8, 9, 10

Comment: Primary key values are always unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window version of `COUNT`:

```
SELECT RowNumber, ID, value
FROM (
  SELECT RowNumber, ID, value, 
         COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS cntOnes,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS cntZeroes
  FROM test
  WHERE value IN (0,1) ) AS t
WHERE cntOnes >= 1 AND cntZeroes >= 1
```

`COUNT(DISTINCT value)` has a value of 2 if *both* `0, 1` values exist within the same `ID` slice.

Comment: Thank you. If my table above is called test, where do I add the From clause? When I attempt to use `COUNT(DISTINCT value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS cnt`  
I keep getting an error   `Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.`

Comment: @AMorton1989 It seems also that `COUNT(DISTINCT ...) OVER ()` is not supported in SQL Server. Please check the edit I made.

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` is indeed not allowed in a windowed version of the `COUNT`, so you can use `MIN` and `MAX` instead.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(RN int, ID int, value int);

INSERT INTO @T (RN, ID, value) VALUES
(1, 001, 1),
(2, 001, 1),
(3, 001, 1),
(4, 002, 1),
(5, 002, 0),
(6, 003, 1),
(7, 003, 1),
(8, 004, 1),
(9, 004, 0),
(10, 004, 1);

WITH 
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN, ID, value
        ,MIN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS MinV
        ,MAX(value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS MaxV
    FROM @T AS T
)
SELECT RN, ID, value
FROM CTE
WHERE MinV <> MaxV
;
```

**Result**

```
+----+----+-------+
| RN | ID | value |
+----+----+-------+
|  4 |  2 |     1 |
|  5 |  2 |     0 |
|  8 |  4 |     1 |
|  9 |  4 |     0 |
| 10 |  4 |     1 |
+----+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #shadowTemp (
    RowNumber int not null,
    Id char(3) not null,
    value bit not null
)

insert into #shadowTemp values ( 1,'001', 0 )
insert into #shadowTemp values ( 2,'001', 1 )
insert into #shadowTemp values ( 3,'001', 1 )
insert into #shadowTemp values ( 4,'002', 0 )
insert into #shadowTemp values ( 5,'003', 0 )
insert into #shadowTemp values ( 6,'003', 1 )

select * from #shadowTemp;

;with cte ( Id ) As (
    select Id
    from #shadowTemp
    group by Id
    having sum( value + 1 ) >= 3
)
select a.* 
from 
#shadowTemp a
inner join cte b on ( a.Id = b.Id )

drop table #shadowTemp
```